# Log4j print wrong color

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I use the below pattern for `log4j`

```
%d{ABSOLUTE}|%highlight{%level{length=3, lowerCase=false}}{TRACE=white bold} | %55.50style{%c{1.1.~.~}.%M[%L]}{yellow} > %highlight{%m%n}{TRACE=white bold}
```

Everything works normally. `log4j` print each part with the correct color except when length of `location of class` exceeds 50 characters. In this case `log4j` can not print properly text color. Please look at the picture. When class name length is less than 50 characters color is yellow which correct with my configuration. But length of class name exceed 50 characters colors is green. How I can solve this problem?

log4j - version 2.17.1
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I wrote to here. if anyone has this kind of problem I hope this help.

I think the problem is when length of class name+method name(in my case) exceeds max character(in my case 50 characters) `style` can not be applied so if you add extra style the second one print correct color

```
%style{%55.50style{%c{1.1.~.~}.%M[%L]}{yellow}}{yellow}
```

This is maybe a bug but currently I could not find other solution